# Django dynamic models.FileField Storage

Tags: django, django-models, filefield

I have a model like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length¶=30)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
```

Is there any way to dynamically change the `Storage` class of `photo`  field based on the value of the `name` field?

for example, I want to store the photo of the persons with the name `xxx` to `FileSystemStorage¶` and for the others I want to use `S3Storage`

Answer (score 5):

I also had a similar use case. Update storage dynamically using the model field `object_storage_name`.
Tried this below code by taking inspiration from the article https://medium.com/@hiteshgarg14/how-to-dynamically-select-storage-in-django-filefield-bc2e8f5883fd

```
class MediaDocument(models.Model):
    object_storage_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    file = DynamicStorageFileField(upload_to=mediadocument_directory_path)


class DynamicStorageFieldFile(FieldFile):

    def __init__(self, instance, field, name):
        super(DynamicStorageFieldFile, self).__init__(
            instance, field, name
        )
        if instance.object_storage_name == "alibaba OSS":
            self.storage = AlibabaStorage()
        else:
            self.storage = MediaStorage()


class DynamicStorageFileField(models.FileField):
    attr_class = DynamicStorageFieldFile

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        if model_instance.object_storage_name == "alibaba OSS":
            storage = AlibabaStorage()
        else:
            storage = MediaStorage()
        self.storage = storage
        model_instance.file.storage = storage
        file = super(DynamicStorageFileField, self
                     ).pre_save(model_instance, add)
        return file
```

It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can assign custom upload location for some specific file.

```
def my_upload_function(instance, filename):
    if instance.name === your_name:
        return your_location

    return generic_location


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length¶=30)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to=my_upload_function)
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to change the storage type. for example, some files have to store in hard disk and the others should store in amazon s3 bucket

Comment: sorry @HasanRamezani i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @HasanRamezani were you able to solve this ? I also have a similar use case. I am unable to find how can I do it.